# How come my login block will not center in reactjs?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to get this block to center. Here is my code:

This is the CSS:

```css
.login__body { 
    display: block; 
    text-align: center; 
    border: 1px solid lightgrey; 
    width: 400px; 
    height: 600px; 
}
```

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function LoginBody() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="login__body">
                <h1>Hello</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
    
export default LoginBody;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `display: flex` to center the element within its parent!

```
function LoginBody() {
    return (
        <div className="login_container">
            <div className="login__body">
                <h1>Hello</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

and here at the css file

```css
.login {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;

  &__container {
   
    display: flex;
    justify-content: 'center';
    align-items: 'center'
  
  }

  &__body {
    // ...
  }
}
```

by doing this, your `.login__container` element with take the whole page and center its child(`.login__body`) in middle of it horizontally and vertically. you can find the documentation details for `flex` property [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex); also [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is a more descriptive and easy article about flex from css tricks

Comment: I am not trying to center the <h1></h1?> I am trying to center the whole block

Comment: Oh Sorry the examples just loaded

Comment: Yes, of course, with adding flex to `.login__container ` the child inside of it `.login__body` will be centered

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Learing react has been quite difficult with all the errors I am getting.